# Display data with jQuery autocomplete with WCF Service?

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi fellow programmers,

I have a database with some data. I Created a WCF Service that uses jQuery Autocomplete to get all names from the database. I get response with JSON but I want to display this in the autocomplete.

This is what my jQuery looks like:

```
$(function () {
    function log(message) {
        $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/service.svc/GetData",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    DataName: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }
    });
});
```

I am fairly new to WCF and want to know what the next step is? How do I map the data so I can display it?

The JSON data output looks like this:

```
{"GetDataResult":[{"Name":"Fran $","CategoryId":102,"dataId":1,"IndexId":16,"InsertedDate":null,"Manual":false}
```

Comment: What does the JSON that `GetData` is serving up look like? Autocomplete expects it to be in a certain format

Comment: I edited the first post.

Comment: So just to be clear, do you want to display `Name` from each result in the array as a suggestion?

Comment: Exactly, if i write for example "Kol" in the input box, I want all the result that has "Kol" do display as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete widget expects the array you supply to the `response` callback function to be in one of the following formats:

1. An array of strings, e.g. `["Hello", "Goodbye"]`
2. An array of objects. Each object must have at least either a `label` property or a `value` property. It may have other properties as well.

So in your situation you can either:

1. Edit the server-side code that returns the JSON to conform to the format that the widget expects, or
2. Modify the results before passing them on to the `response` callback.

I'll focus on #2. The canonical way to do this is to use `$.map` to transform the array you got back from the server into the correct format, and then supply the resulting array to the `response` callback.

In your case that could look something like this:

```js
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data.GetDataResult, function (item) {
        return {
            label: item.Name,
            value: item.dataId
        };
    }));
}
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yntrp063/**

Note that the `value` property's value will be used inside of the textbox after you select an item--that might not be what you want.

Comment: I tried it but I still don't get any autocomplete. I still get the json response though.

Comment: @user3410846 So the `success` callback fires?

Comment: It still fires. So it still gives a response back. But I have to use firebug(Firefox) to see the result that the input gives...

Comment: @user3410846: Have you tried not using `jsonp`? I'm not sure you need it here

Comment: Wow thx dude, putting 'json' instead of jsonp worked. I have no idea why lol.

Comment: @user3410846: `jsonp` is for cross-domain requests and is processed slightly differently, so if you're making a request from the same domain you don't need it.